# Easymock: matcher calls were used outside expectations

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I changed the return value of a method in my code from `void` to and `Object`.
Then two junit test failed stating that an `expect(...).andReturn(...)` was missing. After adding those one test is fixed and the other still throws an exception which seems a bit weird:

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: matcher calls were used outside expectations*

The code which works for one but not the other is:

```
expect(myMock.foo(1l,FooEnum.A)).andReturn(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed to code to

```
expect(myMock.foo(1l,FooEnum.A)).andReturn(new Object());
```

and now it works. It's still strange why I get this error since I definitely return a `new Object` (and not `null` or anything)

Answer (score 7):

`EasyMock.anyObject(String.class)` is a matcher, it isn't a `String` and can't be used as a `String` except for matching - matching being something like the following:

```
when(foo.bar(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class))).thenReturn("foo-bar")
```

P.S. you should avoid using `new String()` whenever possible; it's always better to use `""` instead.

Comment: isnt the `when()` a Mockito method rather than easymock one?

Comment: yeah it's Mockito, I assume theres an equivalent in easymock though

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem with an `AmazonSQSClient` object. I tried `.andReturn(new Object())`, but got an incompatible type error. To fix this, simply return a new object of the type the method expects:

`expect(amazonSQSClient.getQueueAttributes(queueUrl, attributeNames)).andReturn(new GetQueueAttributesResult());`